# angular 6 How to populate the values on ng select multiple option

Tags: angular6, angular-ngselect

I have used ng-select for multiple option and i want populate some values on ng-select.
 I have passed array values in ngmodel but its not working.
Please guide to achieve this

Here is my code

```
companyArr = [10];
companyList = array

<ng-select [items]="companyList" bindLabel="brand_name" bindValue="id"
           [multiple]="true" 
           [(ngModel)]="companyArr" (change)="onSelectCompany($event)" 
           name="companyArr" 
           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && companyArr.invalid }" required> 
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem lies in **bindValue** attribute. 
As per Ng-select Documentation[1]:

> Object property to use for selected model. By default binds to whole object.

Therefore, in order to populate and show data in multiple ng-select input, this attribute needs to be **empty**, since you are binding to the whole object (in this case your number array).

Here is your solution:

```
<ng-select 
    [items]="companyList" 
    bindLabel="brand_name" 
    bindValue=""
    [multiple]="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="companyArr" 
    (change)="onSelectCompany($event)" 
    name="companyArr"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && companyArr.invalid }" 
    required> 
</ng-select>
```

[1]: ng-select GitHub Documentation (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#api)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the values which you are selected with multiple options then you need to store the [value] in an obj, and then you can bind it in typescript...
In my situation I wanted firstname and lastname of an employee which are differnt fields. So I get the value in obj and then concatinate them in typescript so i got my selected employee name As 'Fistname Lastname'...